# Aphorism for ownership

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

So, I have this expression from Portuguese that says that "A dog with two owners dies of hunger"

It has the main objective of expressing that if you assign more than one person to take care of something (usually a problem), they'll all think that the other one will take care of it and end up doing nothing.

Is there anything similar in English? I thought about "Too many cooks spoil the broth" but it doesn't have the same intrinsic message - this one comes across to me that if you have too many people taking care of the same thing, there will be too much done and in the end it will get bad from EXCESS of action, while the Portuguese saying has the underlying meaning of neglect.

Comment: I think [*the tragedy of the commons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) is a relevant expression here (if *everyone* is responsible for looking after something, then in practice *no-one* looks after it). There's also [*diffusion / dissipation of responsibility,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility) recognised as a problem within many large organisations.

Comment: It's also called [bystander apathy](https://personalmba.com/bystander-apathy/), but I know of no idiom that fully conveys it.

Comment: In my experience on the other hand a cat with two owners usually manages to eat very well.

Comment: Getting the right nuance in another language is difficult. Another suggestion (which I don't feel is exactly right, is ['Buridan's ass'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass) which is more about the inability to make a decision.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Diffusion of responsibility is exactly what the expression is about. Tragedy of the commons is more about selfishness, I think (everybody uses the common resource in self-interest and ends up draining the common resource so much it is unrecoverable). Well, sometimes there is no translation and this is life for you.

Comment: "A slave with two masters is a free man" celebrates a positive aspect of unclear responsibility.

Comment: I don't know, but to add the obligatory Douglas Adams reference, that poor dog has a ["somebody else's problem field"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else%27s_problem) around it.

Comment: @WillCain I tried that one but it fell flat. Oh, the woes of being the only nerd in the group :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of expressions that don't quite make it.

"A man with one watch knows what time it is. A man with two is never quite sure." Does not quite get it since it talks about one owner and two possessions instead.

"Too many cooks spoil the broth." Again, it's not quite the same. Overly competitive chefs getting in each other's way is not the same as forgetting to feed the dog. With two chefs the dog might eat badly prepared food but he would eat.

"Go ask your mother. Go ask your father." It's almost getting it. Here each parent is pushing responsibility to the other parent.

"Next window please." That almost gets it, but it's often straight-up lazy or straight-up nastiness rather than the idea that the clerk thinks another clerk really will do the job. Or it's just that the clerk really is going on his scheduled lunch break.

Comment: The "Go ask your mother. Go ask your father." is the closest one, I think. But well, not all expressions or idioms translate well and that's life. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it qualifies as an "aphorism", but [an awful lot of people](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22everyone%20is%20responsible%22%20%22no-one%20is%20responsible%22) have observed that...

> *When/If everyone is responsible [then] no one is responsible*

Answer (score 1):

The British English expression "to fall between two stools" usually means to vascillate between
 two courses of action but it can also mean to be neither one thing nor another as shown by [this Longman's dictionary entry](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fall-between-two-stools) which defines the phrase as

> to be neither one type of thing nor another, or be unable to choose between two ways of doing something

I believe this carries a similar connotation to the Portuguese proverb. The only difference is that the Portuguese does suggest that each owner will leave the feeding of the dog to the other whereas the British phrase is less blame laden.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) The "fall between two stools" for me looks more like Buridan's ass or choice paralysis (inability to choose becoming no choice in the end) and that's not the exact meaning... the Portugese proverb is more about diffusion of responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

A baby with seven nannies has lost its eye (or without an eye).